# Printwriter output not accepting .printf formatters to file?

Tags: java, printwriter

When outputting to an already established file using the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class BarakProductOrder
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //Establish scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Declare variables
        String name, product, street, city, state, zip;
        int qty;
        double price;

        //Collect data
        System.out.println("Welcome to Matt's Dog Food Emporium!\n\nWhat is your name?");
        name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Which product would you like to order today?");
        product = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("How many would you like?");
        qty = input.nextInt();
        price = 4.56*qty;

        input.nextLine(); //Must be placed to not skip over "address" line

        System.out.println("Enter your street address:");
        street = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the City:");
        city = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the State (ex.: NY):");
        state = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the Zip:");
        zip = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Thank you for your order, " + name);

        //Output data to file "BarakOrder.txt"
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\fbara\\Desktop\\CISS 110\\BarakOrder.txt");
        outputFile.println("Order Number: 001");
        outputFile.println("Product: " + product);
        outputFile.println("Quantity: " + qty);
        outputFile.printf("Price = 4.56*" + qty + " = $" + "%.2f" + price);
        outputFile.println("Customer Contact Info: " + name);
        outputFile.println("Address: " + street);
        outputFile.println(city + ", " + state + " " + zip);

        //Close scanner and file object
        input.close();
        outputFile.close();
        System.out.println("Data has been written.");
    }
}
```

Using the "%.2f" modifier at line 45 gives me the following error message:

> java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%.2f'     at
>   java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.PrintWriter.format(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.PrintWriter.printf(Unknown Source)    at
>   BarakProductOrder.main(BarakProductOrder.java:45)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)

Am I using the wrong modifier at the `outputFile.printf`? Or wrong ".print()" line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `printf` works; you give it a format then the things to print.

You're not passing anything to format with the `%.2f`, you're trying to add it. The docs provide info on how to use it (and there are many examples in the world).

Roughly:

```
outputFile.printf("Price = 4.56*" + qty + " = $" + "%.2f", price);
```

Although I'm not sure why you wouldn't do the same formatting for `qty`.

Comment: ahh, the dreaded comma...guess I need to pay more attention. Yes that solved it, thank you. Qty is an int, why would I need it there?

Comment: @FaridB You wouldn't *need* it, but since you're already formatting, IMO it's easier to read without the string concatenation.